# pdflatex can load image properly, but not latex

Tags: graphics

I am using TexStudio 2.6.6.

The `pdflatex` command worked properly for loading an image file in the following minimal working example.

The full command for `pdflatex` is

```
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
```

But this `latex` command did not work properly.

```
"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/latex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
```

The error message is:

```
Cannot determine size of graphic in XiSm11.JPG (no BoundingBox). ...ics[scale=0.8,keepaspectratio]{XiSm11.JPG}
```

---

The minimal working example is:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno,twoside]{amsart}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{ifpdf}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}


  \addtolength{\textheight}{2cm}
  \addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
  \addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
  \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1cm}
  \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1cm}

  \numberwithin{equation}{section}
  \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
  \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
  \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
  \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
  \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
  \newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
  \usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
  \usepackage{cleveref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
  \usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
  \crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

  \newcommand*{\C}{\mathbb{C}}%.............................C
  \newcommand*{\R}{\mathbb{R}}%.............................R
  \newcommand*{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}%.............................Q
  \newcommand*{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}%.............................Z
  \newcommand*{\N}{\mathbb{N}}%.............................N
  %\newcommand*{\F}{\mathbb{F}_q}%...................finite field of q elements

  \newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
  %................................
  %\def\baselinestretch{2}%.espacement des lignes
  %................................
  \title[short]
        {long} 
  \author[initial]{full name}
  %
  \date{Version of \today}
  %................................
  \subjclass[2010]{11M20, 11M26, 43A50}
  \keywords{keyword1,keyword2}
  %
  \AtBeginDocument{%
  %\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,mathic = true}
  \begin{abstract}
  abstract
  \end{abstract}
  \maketitle
  %\tableofcontents % Table of Contents
  }
  %..........................................
  \begin{document}

  \footnotetext{email@yahoo.com}
  %
  \section{Introduction}

  hello
  %
  %figure 7 XiSm11
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.8,keepaspectratio]{XiSm11.JPG}
  \caption{caption}
  \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

I would like to learn a way to load an image with the `latex` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only format you can include while compiling with `latex` is `eps`, so if you wish to compile with `latex` instead of `pdflatex` you will need to convert your figures into `eps` format. `pdflatex`, on the other hand, allows you to use `pdf`, `png`, `jpg`, and `eps` (via `epstopdf`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am using snipping tool and it can only generate JPG/PNG/GIF format file.  How can I convert JPG to EPS?

Comment: @mike If you open the jpg/png/gif in most image editors you should be able to save the file in eps format. I haven't done this in a long time, but I'm pretty sure GIMP does this, as do many others. You could also convert from the command line using ImageMagick.

Comment: Glad I could help!