# how to add color images in latex file

Tags: graphics, color

This is a follow-up of my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215849/pdflatex-can-load-image-properly-but-not-latex) regarding loading image using `latex` command. @erik kindly informed me that `latex` only supports images in `eps` format.
I converted my `JPG` file to an `eps` file using `bmeps.exe` in the `miktex/bin` directory. I can see the image in the dvi file generated by `latex`.  But the original color image in the `JPG` file becomes a black-white or gray scale image in the `eps` file. Is it possible to get a color image in eps format using `bmeps.exe`? Does `latex` support color image?

A minimum woking example can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215849/pdflatex-can-load-image-properly-but-not-latex).

Comment: Why, why, why do you convert jpg to eps and then use dvi mode? What advantage do you hope to get?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I am submitting a paper to arxiv.org. It requires me to submit the source file because the pdf generted by pdflatex is not allowed. The arxiv site only use 'latex' and it does not load image in JPG format. So I have to convert the images to eps format so that they can be loaded into arxiv site.  If there is a better and easy way to get paper accepted by arxiv.org, please let me know.

Comment: Quote from the website: [arXiv fully supports and recognizes PDFLaTeX.](http://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#pdflatex)

Comment: @Johannes_B. Thanks a lot for the info. When I first submitted the .pdf file generate by pdflatex.  It did not work.  Maybe I am missing the flag (\pdfoutput=1). Arxiv website also mentioned that "You can ensure pdflatex processing by setting \pdfoutput=1 within the first 5 lines of the preamble of the main pdflatex file".  Where should I do it? in the .tex file?

Comment: If i understood them correctly, you shall send them the tex-files. All of them, along with the figures. *Not* the final pdf-output.

Comment: OK. I will try as you suggested.  Best-

Comment: @Johannes_B. It worked. I successfully submitted a preprint to arxiv. Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output of `bmeps -h` on the terminal, we see the following options:

```
bmeps [options] [ <inputfile> [ <outputfile> ] ]

      Options
      -------

      -p <pslevel>           select one of the following
         1                   (PS level 1)
         2                   (PS level 2 = default)
         3                   (PS level 3)
      -b                     BoundingBox file only
      -c                     turns color printing on
      -g                     turns color printing off (default)
...
```

So, you need to add the `-c` option to your command:

```
bmeps -c filename.jpg filename.eps
```